# Unix for loop, prompt for value. Read value into ArrayVar[i]

Tags: unix, loops, if-statement, while-loop, nested

I am trying to do a nested if statement inside of a while loop. I get a
unexpected "end of file".

```sh
while :
do
  if [ "$CHOICE" != "x" -o "$CHOICE != "X" ]
  then
    echo "Enter two whole numbers seperated by a space ex:1 123"
    read Num1 Num2
    if echo "$Num1$Num2" | egrep '^[0-9]+$' 2>/dev/null
    then
      # Num1 and Num 2 are INTS
      break
    else
      break
    fi
  else
    # One of the numbers is not an INT
    printf 'Error: You did not enter two whole numbers, Try Again.\n\n'
    continue
  fi
done
echo "$Num1 $Num2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ "$CHOICE" != "x" -o "$CHOICE != "X" ]
                                 ^
                                /
       missing closing quote ---
```